# Override property type

Tags: c#, properties, overriding, derived-class

Referring to the answer provided to my question on [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39880/modeling-issue-with-derived-types/39881?noredirect=1#39881), I couldn't get how to override Agents property to get OrigineAgents. 
 How can I do override the property Agents in my case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I ended up with Origine type has two lists: Agents and OrigineAgents.

since Origine class inherits Region class, you can remove OrigineAgents lists.

Comment: but how can I access to OrigineAgent Properties ? could you illustrate a bit ?

Comment: why did you need OrigineAgents property?
i think, you can use Agents for both class